# All custom attributes lost when I submit forgotPassword- AWS cognito

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm building an Angular web app and using Cognito for user management. And I have to do a function to reset the password when the user forgets.

- My code

  ```
   async ConfirmResetPass(): Promise<void> {
    const Username = this.email;
    const code = this.resetPasswordForm.controls['confirmCode'].value;
    const password = this.resetPasswordForm.controls['password'].value;
    return Auth.forgotPasswordSubmit(Username, code, password)
      .then((data) => {
        this._router.navigate(['auth/sign-in']);
        this._notification.show(`SUCCESS!`);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        this._notification.show(`err: ${e.message}`);
      });
  }
  ```

When results return Success and all custom attributes in cognito lost!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygJ6J.png)

I don't know why! Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?